# Getting exception while querying Oracle using Hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, gwt, oracle11g

Am getting the following exception while executing a select query in my GWT application.

```
2013-01-15 19:36:34,407  WARN [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] [btpool0-0] (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:100) - SQL Error: 28001, SQLState: 99999
2013-01-15 19:36:34,407 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] [btpool0-0] (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:101) - ORA-28001: the password has expired
ORA-02063: preceding line from LOCAL
```

Unable to figure out the reason. Could some one help me to resolve this issue?

Oracle Version    : 11g

Hibernate Version : 3.4.0

thanks in advance.

Comment: log in once through SQL*Plus, it should give you the opportunity to change the expired password.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says, the password has expired. You need to check your credentials and the credentials in your properties `file` or `db.xml` file. Can you log in with your credentials from command line?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows, try this. This is used to reset the password:

```
set ORACLE_HOME=<YOUR_ORACLE_HOME>;
set ORACLE_SID=<SID>
Sqlplus / as sysdba
startup ;
```

After database started up ;

```
SQL > alter user <USERNAME> identified by <password >
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is one of two things:

1) Your password has expired, you need to update it.

2) The system **thinks** your password is expired, you need to update it.

This can be solved quite easily if you open SQL Developer and do the following:

Right click on the connection -> Change password

If you are running multiple databases (such as a test and production)  change the password in all places, this may sound off, but there are other questions that have this same problem resolution.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479781/ora-28001-the-password-has-expired-not-fixable)